# Lazy Loading related Domain Objects: Where/How to store the key?

Tags: php, oop, lazy-loading

Once I have loaded a domain object from the database I have the key to some of its related objects.  For example, when I load an "Organisation", I know the ID of the related "Owner".

I want the Owner property to be lazy loaded, since there's no guarantee I'll be using it during the request or session.

So, the way I see it, the Organisation object could either:

1. Have an OwnerId property and an Owner property.  The Owner property would only be filled on demand (using OwnerId for the lookup).  In this case, the only (small) challenge is keeping the two properties synchronised; or
2. Have an Owner property only.  This would initially contain the key (integer) to lookup the Owner.  If the Owner is called upon, the value would be replaced by an Owner object.  In this case, the (small) challenge would be to avoid type-casting problems.

Which approach is best?  Any why?  Or are there other approaches?  Something else I'm missing?

I'm using PHP, with domain, mapper and service layers.  Your thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Definitely 1 IMHO, as having any data store of an indeterminate type (starts as int, converted to obj on demand) is very bad practice and will result in unmaintainable code. I know PHP's loose typing is useful sometimes, but I certainly never convert from scalars to vectors in a single property/variable. And I have to say I don't understand why you say `the only ... challenge is keeping the two properties synchronised` - why is this? Surely these are effectively read-only properties anyway, what is going to knock them out of sync?

Comment: It is with regret that I have to vote to close this as NC, because `this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion` - although don't take this personally as I think it is a good and well asked question, it's just not really suitable for SO because of that constraint.

Comment: I agree with DaveRandom, #1 is the better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Option 1 (see above) and it's panning out fine.